# HTTP Request Payload in Sencha Touch FormPanel

Tags: php, http, post, request, extjs

I am writing a Sencha Touch app. I have a FormPanel which sends a POST request to the server with Request Payload as follows.

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Picture": "",
            "PostedOn": "Wed Oct 05 2011 16:06:28 GMT+0600 (QYZT)",
            "OccurringOn": "Wed Oct 05 2011 16:06:28 GMT+0600 (QYZT)",
            "Title": "Test",
            "Organiser": "Umair",
            "Details": "This is test."
        }
    ]
}
```

How am I supposed to get this data at the server side assuming this is posted to Events.php? I am currently tryong `$_POST["Title"]` but it is not working.

Comment: How do you pass that data in events.php ?

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to capture the request?  If so please post it up here.

Comment: It's Sencha Touch app's FormPanel that sends request. I used chrome Firebug to see the request and copied that request payload from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the [raw post data](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) (either opening the php://input stream or getting from $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA if it's enabled)

Comment: Man you're genius! I received the data!

Answer (score 0):

What does `print_r($_POST)` in events.php show?

You may need to do:

```
$postvars=json_decode($_POST); // or $postvars=json_decode($_POST['records']);
echo $postvars['records']['title']; // or echo $postvars['title'];
```

Or similar. I am aware that Sencha frameworks often encode posted vars (though typically not by default for AJAX)

Comment: Is this what's returned by the script following it being sent the variables? If this is the case, the POST request is not being made. Are you sure the form is set to POST and not GET?

Comment: if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") is true

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are sending json data, so you should use json_decode() on it before trying to access variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you are posting json data from your client then it send request with `content type` `application/json`. So nothing will show if you `dump $_POST`. You need to `decode` `post data` using `json_decode($_POS['records'])`. then access your data from the decoded array.

Comment: `json_decode`, per documentation, returns: "...the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type." Which is this case looks like an object. Just so you reference it correctly to get the data you want out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `PHP` code you asked for:

```
<?php
    $records = json_decode($_POST['records']);
    $data = $records->Title
?>
```

Be sure to properly sanitize anything sent through a `POST` though before you do something with it as it can be manipulated before it's sent.